# How To Make Auto Increment Number Java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm making method for automatic number but this number is stuck only to number P-011. How to fix it ?

```
private void outomatic_number(){
        try {
            open_db();
            String sql="select right (no_rm,2)+1 from pasien";
            ResultSet rs=stm.executeQuery(sql);
            if(rs.next()){
                rs.last();
                String no=rs.getString(1);
                while (no.length()<3){
                    no="00"+no;
                    txtno.setText("P-"+no);}
                }
            else
            {
               txtno.setText("P-001"); 
            }
            } catch (Exception e) 
            {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you call `rs.last()`, it seems likely that there is more than one record in `pasien`.

You need to remember that a SQL `SELECT` statement returns data in **arbitrary order** if there is no `ORDER BY` clause.

Since you don't have an `ORDER BY` clause, the "last" record is not necessarily the record with the highest number.

Add an `ORDER BY` clause to fix the code.

Comment: Add `ORDER BY` like this ?  `String sql="SELECT RIGHT (kode,2)+1 FROM obat ORDER BY kode DESC";`

Answer (score 0):

it is not necessary that last element of ResultSet is the highest number of it. Instead of these you can use "order by desc". It will return the las number first then take first element of it.